# How do I capture strings between a string match and a new line while ignoring newline and space in between in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, git-bash

I have a bunch of manifest files I am trying to iterate over to extract Import-Packages out of them. The Import-Package is new line delimited and is followed by a space for all continuous package imports until the import statement is over.
It is then followed by a new line and no space for the next attribute (uri in this case). I need to read only the import package attribute i.e. import package followed by all newline and then space patterns.

A sample manifest import statement looks like this

```
Bnd-LastModified: 1494408636933
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Import-Package: com.advantco.base,com.advantco.base.logging,com.advant
 co.base.mime,com.advantco.base.net,com.advantco.base.variablesubstitu
 tion,com.advantco.rest,com.advantco.rest.auth,com.advantco.rest.auth.
 oauth2,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.adapter,
 com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.iface,com
 .advantco.sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.meta
 data,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.
 auth,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.metadata,com.advantco.sugarcrm.c
 ore.rest.op,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.op.v10,com.advantco.sugar
 crm.core.rest.parser,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.object,co
 m.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.xml,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.r
 est.service,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.result,com.advantco.sugarcrm.c
 ore.result.v10,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.service,com.advantco.sugarc
 rm.core.util,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.xml,javax.activation,javax.cr
 ypto,javax.crypto.spec,javax.mail,javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.parsers,ja
 vax.xml.stream,javax.xml.transform,javax.xml.transform.dom,javax.xml.
 transform.stream,org.apache.commons.codec.binary,org.apache.commons.c
 ollections4.map,org.apache.commons.httpclient,org.apache.commons.http
 client.util,org.json
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))"
Tool: Bnd-3.3.0.201609221906
Export-Package: com.advantco.sugarcrm.core;uses:="com.advantco.base.lo
 gging,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object";version="1.0.0",com.advantco
 .sugarcrm.core.adapter;uses:="com.advantco.base,com.advantco.base.log
 ging,com.advantco.base.net,com.advantco.base.variablesubstitution,com
 .advantco.sugarcrm.core,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco
 .sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.metadata";ver
 sion="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error;version="1.0.0",com.adv
 antco.sugarcrm.core.iface;uses:="com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com
 .advantco.sugarcrm.core.object";version="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm
 .core.object;uses:="com.advantco.base,com.advantco.base.mime,com.adva
 ntco.base.net,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.
```

Uri or Required Capability or Export Package cant be hardcoded, could be some other flag after Import-Package so I need to read all lines including Import-Package and all new lines followed by space that follow import package till I get a line followed by a new attribute field and not a space preceding it (not necessarily a given Header).

Output to be like

```
Import-Package: com.advantco.base,com.advantco.base.logging,com.advant
 co.base.mime,com.advantco.base.net,com.advantco.base.variablesubstitu
 tion,com.advantco.rest,com.advantco.rest.auth,com.advantco.rest.auth.
 oauth2,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.adapter,
 com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.iface,com
 .advantco.sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.meta
 data,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.
 auth,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.metadata,com.advantco.sugarcrm.c
 ore.rest.op,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.op.v10,com.advantco.sugar
 crm.core.rest.parser,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.object,co
 m.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.xml,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.r
 est.service,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.result,com.advantco.sugarcrm.c
 ore.result.v10,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.service,com.advantco.sugarc
 rm.core.util,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.xml,javax.activation,javax.cr
 ypto,javax.crypto.spec,javax.mail,javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.parsers,ja
 vax.xml.stream,javax.xml.transform,javax.xml.transform.dom,javax.xml.
 transform.stream,org.apache.commons.codec.binary,org.apache.commons.c
 ollections4.map,org.apache.commons.httpclient,org.apache.commons.http
 client.util,org.json
```

which I can then strip the new lines to look like

```
Import-Package:com.advantco.base,com.advantco.base.logging,com.advantco.base.mime,com.advantco.base.net,com.advantco.base.variablesubstitution,com.advantco.rest,com.advantco.rest.auth,com.advantco.rest.auth.oauth2,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.adapter,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.iface,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.metadata,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.auth,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.metadata,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.op,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.op.v10,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.xml,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.service,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.result,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.result.v10,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.service,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.util,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.xml,javax.activation,javax.crypto,javax.crypto.spec,javax.mail,javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.parsers,javax.xml.stream,javax.xml.transform,javax.xml.transform.dom,javax.xml.transform.stream,org.apache.commons.codec.binary,org.apache.commons.collections4.map,org.apache.commons.httpclient,org.apache.commons.httpclient.util,org.json
```

I am trying this but it dosent seem to work for cases where the header following the import packages is in small case. (Here it is Import-Packge: *package-names* …… Require-Capability: later but in some cases its Import-Packge: *package-names* …… url: which then gets captured.)

```
`sed -n -e '/Import-Package/,/[A-Z]/ p'`
```

But if Manifest is like this

```
Bnd-LastModified: 1494408636933
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Import-Package: com.advantco.base,com.advantco.base.logging,com.advant
 co.base.mime,com.advantco.base.net,com.advantco.base.variablesubstitu
 tion,com.advantco.rest,com.advantco.rest.auth,com.advantco.rest.auth.
 oauth2,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.adapter,
 com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.iface,com
 .advantco.sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.meta
 data,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.
 auth,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.metadata,com.advantco.sugarcrm.c
 ore.rest.op,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.op.v10,com.advantco.sugar
 crm.core.rest.parser,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.object,co
 m.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.xml,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.r
 est.service,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.result,com.advantco.sugarcrm.c
 ore.result.v10,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.service,com.advantco.sugarc
 rm.core.util,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.xml,javax.activation,javax.cr
 ypto,javax.crypto.spec,javax.mail,javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.parsers,ja
 vax.xml.stream,javax.xml.transform,javax.xml.transform.dom,javax.xml.
 transform.stream,org.apache.commons.codec.binary,org.apache.commons.c
 ollections4.map,org.apache.commons.httpclient,org.apache.commons.http
 client.util,org.json
url:http://sample.org
```

then sample.org also gets captured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP told `uri` string shouldn't be hard coded, so adding this solution now.

```
awk '
/Import-Package/{
  flag=1
  val=$0
  next
}
flag && /^ / && NF{
  gsub(/^ /,"")
  val=val?val $0:$0
  next
}
flag && !/^ / && NF{
  print val
  flag=val=""
}'  Input_file
```

output will be as follows.

```
Import-Package: com.advantco.base,com.advantco.base.logging,com.advantco.base.mime,com.advantco.base.net,com.advantco.base.variablesubstitution,com.advantco.rest,com.advantco.rest.auth,com.advantco.rest.auth.oauth2,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.adapter,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.iface,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.metadata,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.auth,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.metadata,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.op,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.op.v10,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.xml,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.service,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.result,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.result.v10,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.service,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.util,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.xml,javax.activation,javax.crypto,javax.crypto.spec,javax.mail,javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.parsers,javax.xml.stream,javax.xml.transform,javax.xml.transform.dom,javax.xml.transform.stream,org.apache.commons.codec.binary,org.apache.commons.collections4.map,org.apache.commons.httpclient,org.apache.commons.httpclient.util,org.json
```

---

---

***1st Solution:*** Could you please try following, considering that your actual Input_file is same as shown samples.

```
awk '
/^uri/{
  flag=""
}
/^Import/{
  flag=1
}
flag{
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  val=val?val $0:$0
}
END{
  print val
}' Input_file
```

***2nd Solution:*** Adding solution using `RS` here.

```
awk -v RS="uri:" 'FNR==1{gsub(/\n|\n +/,"");print}'  Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** Using `RS` and `FS` both here.

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="uri:" '{gsub(/\n|\n +/,"",$1);print $1}'  Input_file
```

***4th Solution:*** Adding 1 more solution using `match` keyword with `awk`.

```
awk -v RS=""  -v FS="\n" 'match($0,/Import.*uri/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/\n|\n +|uri$/,"",val);print val}' Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** In case you have only 1 time this type of line to print then you could add `exit` after `print` statement of both above codes too.

Comment: Uri cant be hardcoded, could be some other flag after Import-Package so I need to read all lines including Import-Package, all new lines followed by space till I get a ned line followed by a new attribute field (not necessarily uri).

Comment: @Sameer, could you please let me know if EDITed solutions helped you.

Comment: No, It does not work, I updates the question with a much better sample imput.

Comment: @Sameer, why don't you mention all conditions in single shot itself, not sure why we have got DOWN VOTE also for even trying hard for trying to help.

Comment: I will revoke it and convert to upvote, I think it was harsh on my part, I just uploaded the whole thing to give the right file but it doesn't work in the older case also, I am relatively new here so don't know the protocol. Apologies for the downvote, edit it and I will then be able to remove it.

Comment: @Sameer, it is pretty simple, ask question in simple manner by providing sample of input and sample of output(DO NOT change questions frequently). On voting side, if someone is NOT clear then give the benefit of doubt to posters rather than giving negative votes. Give negative votes if answer is really needed any improvement please. try to encourage people by up votes if you want. Let me check on your new input one, if possible remove down vote for whoever tried to help you.

Comment: sed -n -e '/Import-Package/,/[A-Z]/ p', I was using this earlier and it works if the next header after Import-Package starts with a Capital Letter, like require capability but it failes if the next header is a small case header like uri:.

Comment: @Sameer, my EDIT code is perfectly working fine for me see output which I posted under EDIT section. can you check one thing do `cat -v your_file` once and see of you have control M characters in it?

Comment: Is it not possible for `Import-Package:` to be the last block of data in the file? Possibly even a short list so that it's the last *line* of the file?

Comment: If you plan to downvote anyone who fails to get exactly the result you wanted, you'd best be careful to provide perfect questions the first time...

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Stackverflow will let me only upvote back once there is an edit, it wasnt there earlier, but now its there so I upvoted back :)

Comment: @Sameer, sure, did you check my previous comments? I could get correct answer see my EDIT answer and its output. Then check `cat -v Input_file` if it has carriage characters and let me know then?

Answer (score 1):

My assumptions:

- The line of "Import-Package:" may start in the middle of the file.
- Next attribute is not always "uri".

Then how about:

```
awk '/^Import-Package:/,!/^Import-Package:/&&!/^ / {
     if (!line || sub(/^ /, "")) line = line $0}
     END {print line}
' sample.txt
```

It reads from the line of "Import-Package:" until the line of next attribute (which is discarded), concatenating the lines by removing the leading whitespace.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer so it will work regardless of `AWK` version. It should work for both of your samples.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of `awk` responses, but this is perfectly doable in `sed` too.

> If you just want the block printed as-is:

```
$: sed -n '
 /^Import-Package: /,/^[^ ]/ {
    /^Import-Package:/ p;
    /^ / p;
 }
' infile
```

Which can be all stacked on one line in GNU `sed`.

```
$: sed -n '/^Import-Package: /,/^[^ ]/ { /^Import-Package:/ p; /^ / p; }' infile
```

## Explained

```
$: sed -n ' ...     ' infile
```

using `sed` with `-n` to prevent any output unless by explicit command; reading from (in this example) a file named `infile`, adjust as you need. Within the single-quotes, the program reads:

```
 /^Import-Package: /,/^[^ ]/ {
    /^Import-Package:/ p; 
    /^ / p;
 }
```

Starting on any line that begins with `Import-Package:` , and continuing through any subsequent line that starts with any non-space (here, *explicitly* a space character), do all commands from this opening curly-brace until the matching close-curly.

Within that block, for any line that starts with `Import-Package:`, print it. For any line that starts with a space, print it.

There is no command to print on any line that starts with a nonspace that isn't `Import-Package:`, so if there is another block started below it, it won't print that one, and the toggle will go out of range, so it won't print anything else unless another `Import-Package:` block starts.

If the block ends the file, the code scope will never go out of range, so it will print until it runs out of records.

> If you want it to print the block all on one line with spaces removed -

```
$: sed -n '
 /^Import-Package: /,/^[^ ]/ {
    /^Import-Package:/ { h; d; }
    /^ / H;
    /^[^ ]/ { s/.*//; x; s/\n* //g; p; d;   }
    $       {         x; s/\n* //g; p; d;   }
 }
' infile
```

For lines from `/^Import-Package: /` to any non-space first character,

- if the line starts with `Import-Package:` replace the hold space with it, and delete it from the pattern space to trigger a clean next read.
- if the line starts with a space, add it to the hold space
- if a line starts with a non-space, scrub it with `s/.*//`; the rest also applies on the last line (`$`), so in either case, `x` puts the accumulated hold space back into the pattern space (technically it swaps them), `s/\n* //g` replaces all newline-space sequences with nothing (removes them), `p` prints the line, and `d` deletes it for a clean buffer to start the next cycle (which, at the end of the file, exits.)

---

> The rest of this is an unnecessary alternative,

... but since I misread the request the first time I left it in case it might help someone else.

If you wanted all the packages broken out and printed each on a line of its own (which is what I first thought you meant), then

```
$: sed -n '
 $ {
  /^Import-Package: / {
    s/^Import-Package: //; s/,/\n/g; p;
  }
 }
 /^Import-Package: /,/^[^ ]/ {
    /^Import-Package:/ { s/^Import-Package://; h; n; }
    /^ / H;
    /^[^ ]/ { s/.*//; x; s/\n* //g; s/,/\n/g; p; d;   }
    $       { s/.*//; x; s/\n* //g; s/,/\n/g; p; d;   }
 }
' infile
```

If it is not possible that `Import-Package:` could begin on the last line of the file, you can remove the `$` block at the top. If it can't be the last block in the file, you can remove the `$` line at the bottom of the main block too.

c.f. the [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) for breakdowns of each command - if you like, I will come back and elaborate here.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^Import-Package:/{:a;N;s/\n //;ta;P;D}' file
```

Use the `-n` option to explicitly print text. Starting from the first line that starts `Import-Package:` append the following line. If that appended line begins with a space, remove it and if the substitution was successful repeat until a line is appended that does not match. Then print the first line of the pattern space and then delete the first line of the pattern space and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl

```
perl -0777 -ne ' s/.*(Import-Package:.+?)\n(?=\S)(.*)/$1/smog; print ' sameer.pkg
```

to remove the newlines

```
perl -0777 -ne ' s/.*(Import-Package:.+?)\n(?=\S)(.*)/$1/smog; print ' sameer.pkg | tr -d '\n'

Import-Package: com.advantco.base,com.advantco.base.logging,com.advant co.base.mime,com.advantco.base.net,com.advantco.base.variablesubstitu tion,com.advantco.rest,com.advantco.rest.auth,com.advantco.rest.auth. oauth2,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.adapter, com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.iface,com .advantco.sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.meta data,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest. auth,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.metadata,com.advantco.sugarcrm.c ore.rest.op,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.op.v10,com.advantco.sugar crm.core.rest.parser,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.object,co m.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.xml,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.r est.service,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.result,com.advantco.sugarcrm.c ore.result.v10,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.service,com.advantco.sugarc rm.core.util,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.xml,javax.activation,javax.cr ypto,javax.crypto.spec,javax.mail,javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.parsers,ja vax.xml.stream,javax.xml.transform,javax.xml.transform.dom,javax.xml. transform.stream,org.apache.commons.codec.binary,org.apache.commons.c ollections4.map,org.apache.commons.httpclient,org.apache.commons.http client.util,org.json
```